# React Search Filter Using Hooks Context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

```
const initialState = {
    data:[],
    filtered: null
};

//@ts-ignore
export const XContext = createContext();

const xReducer = (state:any, action: any) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'FETCH_X':
            const { data } = action.payload;
            console.log(action.payload,"HEY");
            return {...state, data};

        case 'FILTER_X':
            filtered: state.data.filter((result:any) => {
                const regex = new RegExp(`${action.payload}`, 'ig')
                return (
                    result.plate.match(regex)
                );
            })
        case "CLEAR_FILTER_X":
            return {
                ...state,
                filtered:null
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

I get the data to the flatlist with FETCH_X. later, when a data is entered, I want to update the flatlist with FILTER_X by filtering the data from FETCH_X.

Is my filter x function correct?

I filter the data with the filter x function and wait for the result to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully you are missing `return` in `FILTER_X` case, you are returning to just the `filtered:` statement.

Updated code:

```
case 'FILTER_X':
    const filtered = state.data.filter((result:any) => {
        const regex = new RegExp(`${action.payload}`, 'ig')
        return result.plate.match(regex);
    })
    return {...state, filtered}; // Add this line
```